# Python: basic project structure & import paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

For my Python 3 project, I have the following directory structure:

```
├── myapp
│   ├── compute
│   │   └── compute.py
│   └── mymain.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── compute
        └── compute_test.py
```

My goal is to be able to run the code here in three ways:

- Unit tests. I've randomly chosen `pytest` for these but whichever framework should be fine;
- `python myapp/mymain.py <arguments>` for when I want to do a quick "manual test";
- Something like `pip install` and/or a Docker image for a proper deployment.

Now, the first and third of these seem to be no problem, but I'm having trouble with the middle one.

Here are the contents of the files:

`compute.py`:

```py
import math


class MyComputation:

    # performs an extremely difficult and relevant computation
    @staticmethod
    def compute(i: int) -> float:
        return math.sqrt(abs(i))
```

`compute_test.py`:

```py
import pytest

from myapp.compute.compute import MyComputation


def test_computation_normal_case():
    ins = [-4, 9, -36, 121]
    outs = list(map(lambda i: MyComputation.compute(i), ins))
    expected = [2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 11.0]
    assert outs == expected
```

`mymain.py`:

```py
import random

from myapp.compute.compute import MyComputation


class MyApp:

    @staticmethod
    def main():
        print("Loading data...")
        i = random.randint(1, 100000)
        print("Input:  {}".format(i))
        print("Computing...")
        f = MyComputation.compute(i)
        print("Output: {}".format(f))
        print("Done!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp.main()
```

When I run, say, `pytest` from the command line, it works fine: finds the test, runs it, test passes.

However, when I try to run the main class:

```
$ python myapp/mymain.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myapp/mymain.py", line 8, in <module>
    from myapp.compute.compute import MyComputation
ImportError: No module named myapp.compute.compute
```

It makes no difference whether I add `__init__.py` files inside the directories or not.

But if I add the following to `mymain.py`, it can then be run from the command line as expected:

```py
import os
import sys

root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../'))
sys.path.insert(0, root_path)
```

So, questions:

1) What is the correct, Pythonic, idiomatic way to do the main class? What I want is essentially "run this code here, in-place, as is". Where do I put my main class? Do I need to `pip install` my stuff locally first? Do I need to do the imports differently?

2) Surely the `sys.path.insert()` stuff cannot be the "official" way of accomplishing what I want to do here? There must be a less ridiculous way... right?

3) Why do the unit tests work just fine while the main class doesn't? Does the unit test framework do something similar to the `sys.path.insert()` stuff under the covers? Or is there a better way of handling the imports?

Comment: Can you take a look at PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: You do not have any `__init__.py` in your `compute` package.